# what is difference between max-width and min-width in media query in html css

Tags: css, media-queries

what is difference between max-width and min-width in media query in html css

```
@media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }

@media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }

@media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }

@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }

@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }

@media (max-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }

@media (max-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (max-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }

@media (max-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }

@media (max-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }

@media (max-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Comment: what do you believe `min` (minimum)  and `max` (maximum) stand for? The difference it obvious... `min` addresses all screen with a minimum viewport width while `max` addresses all screens with a maximum viewport width. PS: a max width of 1025px is uncommon for laptops as the smallest laptop screens are around 768x1366px. Which is quite the smallest resolution. I wouldn't call laptops with a max-width of 1281px not high resolution either as it is quite low or minimum resolution.

Comment: starting media queries that address `max-width` starting will not work as intended. because the last media query will be true for all others as well and overwrite them.

Comment: @tacoshy it's true it will overwrite the settings if they are the same settings, but there could be some different ones.

Answer (score 0):

`@media (max-width: 1000px) {// code}` for example means that if the window width is equal to or less than (at maximum) 1000px then the code in the query will trigger.

`@media (min-width: 1000px) {// code}` means that if the window width is equal to or more than (at minimum) 1000px then the code in the query will trigger.

Comment: This is incorrect - think about what 'under' and 'more than' mean.

Comment: OK, now corrected to include the value given.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width:801px)
```

--view width is **atleast** 801px.(There is no max limit but has a minimum limit of 801px)
means  whatever views whose width is greater than or equal to 801px.

```
@media (max-width:600px)
```

--view width is **atmost** 600px.
means whatever views whose width is lesser than or equal to 600px.(has a maximum limit of 600px.there is no minimum limit)